# Variable in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I don't have much experience with JSON, I want to know if something like this is possible.

```
{
    "variable": "A really long value that will take up a lot of space if repeated",

    "array": [variable, variable, variable]
}
```

Obviously that isn't valid, but I want to know if there is a way to do this. I tried using "variable" but of course that just sets the array item to the string "variable". The reason I want to do this is I need to repeat long values in a multidimensional array, which takes up a lot of space.

Thanks.

Comment: you can do that in javascript, then convert it into json, which will basicly repeat the "A really long value..." for each of the elements in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to do some post-processing on the JSON after parsing it, then you can use a token value in your array, and replace the token after parsing with the variable. Example:

```
{
    "variable": "A really long value",
    "array": ["variable", "variable", "variable"]
}
```

Then, in your code that parses:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
for (var i=0; i<obj.array.length; i++)
{
    obj.array[i] = obj[obj.array[i]];
}
```

Comment: Ok, the thing is the JSON is dynamic and could have any number of variables. I'll work something out with this method though, shouldn't be too hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you worried about space in the output, or in the object created from the JSON? In the latter case, it's likely that the string values will be coalesced when the parsing happens.

If you're concerned about the size of the JSON, then you'll probably either want to change to another format, or de-duplicate the strings in the JSON.

You could add an object to your JSON data that maps ID numbers to strings, then use the IDs to represent te strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in pure JSON (full [spec here](http://json.org/)).

If you wanted to do something like that you might want to look into templating tools such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

`you will get your answer here jason tutorial for beginners`

```
example:
  var data={
    "firstName":"Ray",
    "lastName":"Villalobos",
    "joined":2012
  };
```

Comment: I don't like answers wich just dump a link. Please add a short summary for the case that the linked page goes offline.